# Using the dfgproposal and dfgreporting classes

Tags: cross-referencing

I came accorss the dfgproposal and dfgreporting classes which I started to use. In this class the command \dfgprojpapers is defined. As I understand it, it is supposed to generate a small list of references inside the document according to a list of key that is provided. Hwoever, it seems that this command can only be used once? What do I need to do in order to get two seperate list in that fashion?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this by copying the `\dfgprojpapers` command and creating two different versions.
(`\dfgprojpapers` is defined in `dfgproposal.cls` but it's basically only an alias for `\prop@paperlist` from `proposal.cls`.)

```
\makeatletter

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{featureda}
\newcommand\dfgprojpapersa[2][]{%
  \let\biboldfont\bibfont%
  \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}%
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{.9}%
  \nocite{#2}\def\do##1{\addtocategory{featureda}{##1}}\docsvlist{#2}%
  \setkeys{paperlist}{#1}
  \@ifundefined{prop@rl}{}{\@latex@warning{some papers are not classified!}}
  \if@allpapers\printbibliography[category=featureda,heading=empty]\fi%
  \let\bibfont\biboldfont}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{featuredb}
\newcommand\dfgprojpapersb[2][]{%
  \let\biboldfont\bibfont%
  \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}%
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{.9}%
  \nocite{#2}\def\do##1{\addtocategory{featuredb}{##1}}\docsvlist{#2}%
  \setkeys{paperlist}{#1}
  \@ifundefined{prop@rl}{}{\@latex@warning{some papers are not classified!}}
  \if@allpapers\printbibliography[category=featuredb,heading=empty]\fi%
  \let\bibfont\biboldfont}

\makeatother
```

With this you can use the commands `\dfgprojpapersa` and `\dfgprojpapersb` wherever you want you first respectively second list of featured publications.

Keep in mind that you will have to modify the command with which you generate the non-featured bibliography:

```
\printbibliography[
  heading = empty,
  notcategory = featureda,
  notcategory = featuredb,
]
```